# How do you find a python module that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere?

Tags: python, module, ipython, python-import

So I have been given access to a new repo, and I am opening an pre-existing Ipython notebook.

Within that notebook, I have the following line: (foo blah and boo are not the real names obviously, I changed them for the purpose of this question).

```
from foo.blah.boo import some_function
```

I get the `ImportError: foo.blah.boo`of course, since it cannot find this anywhere.

Here is my problem though, I cannot seem to *find* this module anywhere! I have tried grepping for this function definition to no avail, and also I cannot seem to find any directory called `foo` anywhere.

I am at a loss on what I am doing wrong here... thanks!

Comment: I got downvoted but no reason is given.

Comment: I haven't downvote but - you haven't asked a question. We don't know your setup. What are you hoping for us to suggest here?

Comment: It seems the place from where you copied this line was just some example line where they expect you to replace foo blah blah blah with your actual required library. You need to replace it with the once which you need in the code. For example, if you want to plot something, you use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Here `foo` is `matplotlib` and `blah` is `pyplot`. Hope you got what I am trying to say

Comment: @roganjosh Fixed that, its a question now.

Comment: @Bazingaa Yes, however, this is not their actual name. (I changed the name myself for privacy). Its a module name that they created, but I cannot seem to find it anywhere

Comment: It seems that there is no such module (because you wrote that 4 or times). So you cannot find it.

Comment: @zvone Yes. So if you are given such a module name, how do you go about looking for it?

Comment: Well, I'd try to find out if there is someone else using this for whom the code works. Or I'd look at the git history to see who added that import and with what excuse

Comment: This is something that you'll have to work out with the people who gave you access to repo and notebook.  There are so many unknowns that we can't help you from afar.

Comment: @hpaulj Let's ask in a different way. How would one normally find where a package/module is defined, given the names as so?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the person sharing the notebook has a custom PYTHONPATH, i.e., they had a separate directory with their own modules `foo.blah.boo`, so you can't find the module online, or a directory in the repo

Comment: or as @Bazingaa pointed out in your question, you need to replace it with an actual module. `foo`, `blah`, `boo` are usually placeholders in code samples.

Comment: Yeah, I am starting to suspect that... however all the Ipython notebooks in this directory seem to use the same line. PS this is a self-made module I suspect.

Comment: That is not their actual name, I have changed the name for privacy purposes